# What query language is used by AWS Cloudwatch Logs Insights?

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

The AWS guides for insight queries aren't very specific but I wondered what query language it may use or at least, most resemble?

This is the example they give when you navigate to Logs Insights:

fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a custom language inspired by SQL